# how to pass a variable with array in Rest API

Tags: jquery, api

Hi in this below code there are three functions defined.SO it will download three csv files.I am trying to access the video id from downloadcsvsearch function and i need to pick that video id and i need to pass it to the next function that is downloadcsvcomments.how can i do that?

```
  <!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <a href='#' onclick='downloadCSV({ filename: "a.csv" }); downloadCSVV({ filename1:"b.csv"}); downloadCSVVV({ filename2:"c.csv"});'>Download CSV</a>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {});

        function convertArrayOfObjectsToCSV(args) {
            var result, ctr, keys, columnDelimiter, lineDelimiter, data;
            data = args.data || null;
            if (data == null || !data.length) {
                return null;
            }
            columnDelimiter = args.columnDelimiter || ',';
            lineDelimiter = args.lineDelimiter || '\n';
            keys = Object.keys(data[0]);
            result = '';
            result += keys.join(columnDelimiter);
            result += lineDelimiter;
            data.forEach(function(item) {
                ctr = 0;
                keys.forEach(function(key) {
                    if (ctr > 0) result += columnDelimiter;
                    result += item[key];
                    ctr++;
                    console.log("columnDelimiter " + result);
                });
                result += lineDelimiter;
            });
            return result;

        }

        function downloadCSV(args) {
                var youtubeData = [];
            var data, filename, link;

            $.getJSON('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&q=laptops&maxResults=50&key=""', function(data) {
                console.log(data);
                for(var i = 0; i < data.items.length; i++) {
                youtubeData.push({
                    "videoid": data.items[i].id.videoId,
                    "Title": data.items[i].snippet.title
                });
            }
                var csv = convertArrayOfObjectsToCSV({
                    data: youtubeData
                });
                if (csv == null) return;

                filename = args.filename || 'export.csv';

                if (!csv.match(/^data:text\/csv/i)) {
                    csv = 'data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,' + csv;
                }
                data = encodeURI(csv);

                link = document.createElement('a');
                link.setAttribute('href', data);
                link.setAttribute('download', filename);
                link.click();
            });
        }

         function downloadCSVV(args) {
              var youtubeData1 = [];
            var data1, filename1, link;

            $.getJSON('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=kmJM7Z6_DEw,zsvLai5jxCs,N9uMFDotJPg,OlTH_XPlFrw&key=""&part=snippet,statistics', function(data1) {
                console.log(data1);
                for(var i = 0; i < data1.items.length; i++) {
                youtubeData1.push({
                    "videoid": data1.items[i].id,
                    "Id": data1.items[i].snippet.categoryId,
                    "ChannelId": data1.items[i].snippet.channelId,
                    "Title": data1.items[i].snippet.title,
                    // "Description": data.items[i].snippet.description.replace("\n", ""),
                    "Commentcount": data1.items[i].statistics.commentCount,
                    "ViewCount": data1.items[i].statistics.viewCount,
                    "LikeCount": data1.items[i].statistics.likeCount,
                    "DislikeCount": data1.items[i].statistics.dislikeCount,
                    "FavoriteCount": data1.items[i].statistics.favoriteCount
                });
            }
                var csv = convertArrayOfObjectsToCSV({
                    data: youtubeData1
                });
                if (csv == null) return;

                filename1 = args.filename1 || 'export.csv';

                if (!csv.match(/^data:text\/csv/i)) {
                    csv = 'data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,' + csv;
                }
                data1 = encodeURI(csv);

                link = document.createElement('a');
                link.setAttribute('href', data1);
                link.setAttribute('download', filename1);
                link.click();
            });
        }


        function downloadCSVVV(args) {
            var items = [];
            var youtubeData2 = [];
            var data2, filename2, link;
            $.getJSON('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/commentThreads?key=""&textFormat=plainText&part=snippet,replies&videoId=OlTH_XPlFrw&maxResults=60', function(data2) {
                for(var i = 0; i < data2.items.length; i++) {
                youtubeData2.push({
                    "videoid": data2.items[i].snippet.topLevelComment.snippet.videoId,
                    "Authordisplayname": data2.items[i].snippet.topLevelComment.snippet.authorDisplayName,
                    "Textdisplay": data2.items[i].snippet.topLevelComment.snippet.textDisplay,
                });
                }

                console.log(data2);
                var csv = convertArrayOfObjectsToCSV({
                    data: youtubeData2
                });
                if (csv == null) return;

                filename2 = args.filename2 || 'export.csv';

                if (!csv.match(/^data:text\/csv/i)) {
                    csv = 'data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,' + csv;
                }
                data2 = encodeURI(csv);

                link = document.createElement('a');
                link.setAttribute('href', data2);
                link.setAttribute('download', filename2);
                link.click();
            });
        }


    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. The [commentThreads reference](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/commentThreads/list) says that the `videoId` can only contain one string:

> The videoId parameter instructs the API to return comment threads
>   associated with the specified video ID.

If you need comments about multiple videos, you must create multiple requests, one request per one video id.

Comment: so if i have 100 videos i need to call the api with the video id 100 times a?

Comment: Right, if you need to query comments of 100 videos, you'll need to call the API 100 times, one API for one video ID.

Comment: so each and everytime i need to change the video_id in the code.that is not the goodway right?Is there any other way

Comment: I have read through the reference of the `commentThreads` and I don't think there is another way. I think they design the API that way, to enforce the quota policy: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started#quota

Comment: Glad that I did help! If you could mark the answer as correct, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: is there any possibilty to get the multiple video id's in an array in code?

Comment: If you meant to place an array of video ids into the `videoId` field (e.g. `videoId=[m4Jtj2lCMAA,N7Q9V217XjE]`), then the answer is no. If this is not what you're asking, then I don't quite understand your question. Please rephrase!

Comment: Thats what i asked you.But if there is no option to pass the multiple video ids,then how can i complete my task.Actually each and every time i can't change the video id in the code and that is not the good method also right?so what can i do for that?

Comment: if the put multiple id's for this api it is working fine : https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=eDHFc24mp38&key=" "&part=snippet.But this api will get only the descrpiton and title and not comments.So if i want the comments i need to use only that api,and in that api the multiple video ids are not passing..so what can i do?

Comment: Have you tried something a long the line of: 1) have the list of video ids; 2) loop through the list, for each id you'll construct a query and execute the query. Like: `for (id in videoIds) { queryCommentThread(id); }`

Comment: i did not understood what you told.can you tell clearly what you want to tell please.

Comment: It's probably easier if we communicate via email. Please send me an email to tiendatbk_at_gmail.com